# ¿Como poder usar una variable iniciada en un if, en otro, si el if evalúa lo mismo?

Tags: java

Estuve buscando pero no encuentro Una pregunta al respecto, Alguien sabría si hay alguna forma de evitar el error de compilación si yo quiero usar una variable iniciada dentro de un if, en otro if que evalúa exactamente lo mismo pero en otra parte del código que se ejecutará posteriormente. Dejo un ejemplo para que sea un poco mas claro:

```
    boolean esNecesarioObjeto = true;
    Objeto objeto;

    if(esNecesarioObjeto) {
        objeto = new Objeto();
    }

    if(esNecesarioObjeto) {
        objeto.hacerAlgo();
    }
```

Ahora bien, entiendo que el problema sería que Java no puede saber en el segundo if que el primero dio true, y toma como inexistente el objeto o bien no sabe si cambió el estado de la variable booleana, pero quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de lograr identificar ambos if en distintas partes del código de alguna forma. Ahora bien, en mi caso sería algo como esto:

```
boolean esNecesarioObjeto = true;
    Objeto objeto;

    if(esNecesarioObjeto) {
        objeto = new Objeto();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<10;i++) {

        if(esNecesarioObjeto) {
            objeto.hacerAlgo();
        }
    }
```

Y quisiera utilizar la misma instancia de Objeto en todas las iteraciones que precisen usarlo.

Comment: No veo ningun problema de compilacion en tu primer ejemplo, como mucho seria de ejecución si `esNecesariooObjeto` cambia de valor.

Comment: En el primer caso si la condición es la misma sería un sólo if: if(esNecesarioObjeto) {        objeto = new Objeto();   objeto.hacerAlgo();  } En el segundo si objeto no depende del bucle, debería ir el for dentro del if y no al contrario

Comment: ¿Por qué no usar un `while(esNecesarioObjeto)` en tu segundo ejemplo? Ciclo y comprobación en una sola estructura.
De todas formas, a falta de ver más código, tu problema sería más de diseño que del algoritmo.

Answer (score 2):

Si estamos hablando de variables locales, el problema es que el compilador no puede asegurar que en el segundo uso se le haya asignado un valor.

Las variables locales *no cogen valores por defecto*, así que antes de usarlas tiene que haber habido una asignación de un valor (aunque sea `null`).

Este código no compila (*the local variable obj may have not been initialized*)

```
Object obj;
obj.toString();
```

Este código es completamente legal; dará un *warning* y, desde luego, un NPE al ejecutarlo pero se compilará.

```
Object obj = null;
obj.toString();
```

En tu ejemplo, el compilador no hace el análisis para ver si `esNecesarioObjeto` cambia entre los dos `if`; el compilador solo ve:

```
Object objeto;
if (condicionA) {
   // Asignar valor a objeto
}

if (condicionB) {
   // Usar valor a objeto.
}
```

y protesta porque en algunas situaciones (`condicionB && !condicionA`) se podría usar el valor de *objeto* sin haberle asignado valor.

La solución es simplemente asignar un valor (habitualmente, el valor "por defecto del tipo, para los objetos es `null`).

```
boolean esNecesarioObjeto = true;
Objeto objeto = null;

if(esNecesarioObjeto) {
    objeto = new Objeto();
}

if(esNecesarioObjeto) {
    objeto.hacerAlgo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no es necesario poner otro if, si pones tu código de esta forma de pride solucionar lo que mencionas.

```
bolean esNecesarioObjeto = true;
    Objeto objeto;

    if(esNecesarioObjeto) {
        objeto = new Objeto();
    for(int i = 0; i<10;i++) {
            objeto.hacerAlgo();

    }
    }
```

O bien con esta opción:

```
for(int i = 0; i<10;i++) {

    if(esNecesarioObjeto  && objeto!= null) {
        objeto.hacerAlgo();
    }
}
```